# Auto-assigning categories to particular conversations

Tags: vba, outlook, store, categories

I would like to create a macro that sets a category for a MailItem and all other MailItems within the first one's conversation.  The good news is that Microsoft has a demo that does EXACTLY this, [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868084%28v=office.14%29.aspx/).  The bad news is that it doesn't work (gasp).  I would love it if someone could take a look at the code, error and help screenshots below and fix Microsoft's mistake(s), or tell me what I did or forgot to do that is causing this error.

code (from link above):

```
Sub DemoSetAlwaysAssignCategories()
 Dim oMail As Outlook.MailItem
 Dim oConv As Outlook.Conversation
 Dim oStore As Outlook.Store
 ' Get the item displayed in the Reading Pane.
 Set oMail = ActiveExplorer.Selection(1)
 Set oStore = oMail.Parent.Store
 If oStore.IsConversationEnabled Then
 Set oConv = oMail.GetConversation
 If Not (oConv Is Nothing) Then
 Dim oFolder As Outlook.Folder
 oConv.SetAlwaysAssignCategories "Project Convo", oStore
 End If
 End If
End Sub
```

The debugger highlights this line:

```
oConv.SetAlwaysAssignCategories "Project Convo", oStore
```

And gives an error dialog.  Here is the screen shot:
![VBA error][2]
And here is the window from when I click "Help" on that error:
![VBA help][3]

Scratch that, I don't have enough reputation to post pictures.  What an utterly asinine rule.  Anyways, the error says "Run-time error '-2147221233 (8004010f)': The attempted operation failed. An object could not be found." The help button opens up the developer reference entry for the OlkCategory.BackColor Property.  So I assumed I was missing a reference to some library or something, but I can't find much on the internet about this topic, and I thought that the standard Outlook lib would have all the category objects already anyways.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: Oh, did you edit something like this out of my post?  Sorry about that, I will try to keep this in mind for next time!

Answer (score 0):

Is it a a non-delivery store such as an archive .pst store or shared one? Try to run the following code instead:

```
oConv.SetAlwaysAssignCategories "Important", oStore
```

Also I have found a [similar forum thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/90e807f4-8330-4b8d-ac40-3ef0a94fd96f/outlook-08004010f-error-thrown-on-accessing-mounted-mailbox?forum=outlookdev) which describes the same error code.

Comment: To be honest, I don't know the answer to your question because I'm not familiar with stores.  I believe it would be shared, since this is company email using an exchange server. Either way, I tried what you typed and got the same error.  I assumed because of the nature of the error that this wasn't a network-related problem, just a problem with my local machine, but do you think otherwise?

Comment: It looks like the method fails on shared stores. Try to run the code against the local store, not a shared one. Do you get the same error?

Comment: I think you are correct.  I somehow missed this in my hunt before.  I don't really get what it's saying but I believe it is agreeing with your comments: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brijs/archive/2010/07/30/how-to-get-reference-to-public-folder-store-using-outlook-object-model-for-outlook-2010.aspx